# Rendering multiple vue components in laravel 6.x

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and Vue, I've created a navigation component and an article component.

I believe I've setup Vue correctly, the issue is that my navigation vue component is showing but not my article component.

Here is my code:

app.js

```js
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

const files = require.context("./", true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key =>
    Vue.component(
        key
            .split("/")
            .pop()
            .split(".")[0],
        files(key).default
    )
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

app.blade.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <navigation />

        <main class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <articles></articles>
@endsection
```

My navigation is showing but not my articles component, everything is compiling successfully `npm run watch`, I have also restarted the server.

--

Here are the vue components:

Navigation.vue

```js
<template>
  <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
    <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
      <svg
        class="fill-current h-8 w-8 mr-2"
        width="54"
        height="54"
        viewBox="0 0 54 54"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          d="M13.5 22.1c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05zM0 38.3c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05z"
        />
      </svg>
      <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Tailwind CSS</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block lg:hidden">
      <button
        class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white"
      >
        <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <title>Menu</title>
          <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
      <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
        <a
          href="#responsive-header"
          class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
        >Docs</a>
        <a
          href="#responsive-header"
          class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
        >Examples</a>
        <a
          href="#responsive-header"
          class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white"
        >Blog</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0"
        >Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Article.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Articles</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
      article: {
        id: "",
        title: "",
        body: ""
      },
      article_id: "",
      pagination: {},
      edit: false
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchArticles();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchArticles() {
      fetch("api/articles")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools and inspect the Console for any error messages and share if there are any.

Comment: No errors just about Vue being in development mode.

Comment: I can add the vue components to the question @tamrat

Comment: Added the Vue components @tamrat with the file names, both are in the `resources/js/components` folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very small error (bug?) that is very easy to miss. You're doing everything right except for one thing. The code is not working as expected because of this: `<navigation />`. If you, instead change it to: `<navigation></navigation>` it will work as expected.

I am not sure about the exact cause for this problem, but I have read somewhere about Vue not supporting self-terminating tags because they are not valid in HTML5 but I'm not sure. Maybe someone can elaborate on this.

Comment: Not sure I'd call it a bug. it's how just how Vue works. When you're compiling your Vue application in js, the compiler takes care of this for you and it's a non-issue, but for uncompiled Vue, you have to open and close the tags, (as well as use kebab-case)

Comment: @tamrat you saved my life! Thank you very much. In a pure Vue application, however, self-closing tag does work. But probably webpack.mix compiles it in a different way. Might not be called a bug, but there needs to be some kind of explanation available somewhere regarding this. It is a common practice to use self-closing tags if it is not a container element.